# Android Studio: Build another instance of application for testing

Tags: java, android, android-studio-2.0

I have my android application (created in Android Studio) installed on my mobile device. I need to install another instance of this application (for testing on staging server, not production) with a few small fixes - such as url paths.

I know that two applications on a device cannot have the same java package, so what is the best way to solve it?

Comment: change the package name of application from gradle...!!!

Answer (score 0):

For use [product flavors](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Product-flavors) for this.

Each product flavor can have different `applicationId`:

```
android {
    …
    productFlavors {
        prod {
            applicationId "com.example.myapp"
        }
        stage {
            applicationId "com.example.myapp.stage"
        }
    }
}
```

Or you can add `applicationIdSuffix` to a flavor:

```
android {
    …
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myapp"
    }
    productFlavors {
        prod {
        }
        stage {
            applicationIdSuffix ".stage"
        }
    }
}
```

It's also useful if you want to be able to install both release and debug:

```
android {
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
        }
    }
}
```

If you use it in both product flavor and build type, it will be chained, product flavor goes before build type. In this example suffix for `fullDebug` variant would be `".stage.debug"`.